# Find total number of occurrences of a substring

Tags: java, regex

Suppose I want to find total number of occurrences of following substring.

Any substring that starts with 1 followed by any(0 or more) number of 0's and then followed by 1.

I formed a regular expression for it: `1[0]*1`

Then I used the `Pattern` and `Matcher` class of  java to do the rest of the work.

```
import java.util.regex.*;
class P_m
{
 public static void main(String []args)
 {
     int s=0;
     Pattern p=Pattern.compile("1[0]*1");
     Matcher matcher=p.matcher("1000010101");
     while(matcher.find())
      ++s;
     System.out.println(s);
 }
}
```

But the problem is when we have two consecutive substrings that overlap, the above code outputs answer 1 less than actual number of occurrences. For example in above code output is 2 whereas it should be 3. Can I modify above code to return the correct output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
"10*(?=1)"
```

This matches the same pattern as you described (starts with 1, followed by zero or more 0, followed by 1), but the difference is that the final 1 is not included in the match. This way, that last 1 is not "consumed" by the match, and it can participate in further matches, effectively allowing the overlap that you asked for.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("10*(?=1)");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher("1000010101");
int s = 0;
while (matcher.find()) ++s;
System.out.println(s);
```

Outputs 3 as you wanted.